# Как проверить действителен ли пин код в базе данных по его дате?

Tags: mysql

В базе данных в таблице pin_code храню пин коды, дату создания и дату завершения действия пин кода.

MySQL

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM pin_code;
+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
| id       | code           | create_date         | destroy_date   |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
|        1 | 6194027126     | 1605500754          | 1607500754     |
|        2 | 5807462325     | 1607808551          | 1609508551     |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+

 `create_date` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `destroy_date` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

PHP - получаю ответ если пин код имеется и дата его не просрочена.

```
//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pin_code WHERE code=5807462325 AND destroy_date > unix_timestamp(now())");  // destroy_date - дата завершения срока действия пин кода должна быть больше текущей

print '<table border="1">';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["code"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["create_date"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["destroy_date"].'</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
```

Все пин коды имеют уникальные значения

Не получается корректно проверить из PHP скрипта наличие пин кода в базе и определить действителен код или его время истекло (create_date - дата создания кода, destroy_date - дата завершения срока действия пин кода).

**Нужно получить статусы**: пин код есть или нет, пин код действителен (если он есть) или просрочен.

Помогите разобраться с проверками.

Спасибо!

UPD.

Сделал так:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT code, (destroy_date > unix_timestamp(now())) `status` FROM pin_code WHERE code=6194027126");  // destroy_date - дата завершения срока действия пин кода должна быть больше текущей

print '<table border="1">';
if($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
   if($row["status"] == 1){
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["code"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td>';
    print '<td>Пин код действителен</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}else{
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["code"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td>';
    print '<td>Пин код просрочен</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}}else{
print '<td>'.$row["code"].'</td>';
print 'Нет такого пин кода';
}
print '</table>';
```

Задача решена, осталось для статусов задать нужный вывод.

Comment: тип данных create_date и  destroy_date ?

Comment: Тип данных create_date и destroy_date : int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

Comment: в чем проблема? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87cc69/1

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую понять как это работает.

Comment: или так http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87cc69/4

Comment: что понять? Тебе дали ссылку на точно такой же запрос. Или у тебя был вопрос, как можно информацию из запроса получить без цикла while который выводит данные на экран, а как-то по-другому?

Comment: И так работает ))) Буду пробовать применить это в скрипте проверки статуса пин кода.

Comment: @Ипатьев, растерялся просто в самом sqlfiddle.com. Я думал увидеть что-то подобное if проверкам, а увидел что-то более лаконичное.

Comment: тут весь вопрос только в том, как результат использовать.

Comment: то есть код остается в точности такой же как был только без HTML и вместо while пишется if.

Comment: Да, теперь понял. @splash58 напишите ответ, приму его.

Comment: @Иван давайте вы покажете, какой результат вы хотели бы увидеть. пока непонятно даже, что вы спрашиваете

Comment: @splash58, есть форма ввода пин кода, после ее отправки хочу получить результат в виде: код просрочен, такого кода нет, код активет. Т.е. думал что нужно использовать 3 if

Comment: @splash58, в вопрос добавил свое решение, посмотрите, все ли там верно. Спасибо!

Comment: Ужс... особенно то, что дата-время хранится в INT, да ещё и в TIMESTAMP, который подвержен влиянию зоны времени. Ну и выполнение проверок не там, где находятся данные (и где имеется специально заточенный под обработку данных сервер)... хорошо, что в данном конкретном случае на клиента тащится не целиком вся таблица.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN pin_code.code IS NULL                THEN 'не существует.'
            WHEN destroy_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) THEN 'просрочен'
                                                      ELSE 'действителен'
                                                      END AS status
FROM (SELECT '5807462325' code) src
LEFT JOIN pin_code USING (code);
```

Полученный ответ можно напрямую вставлять в создаваемый интерфейс: `print '<td>Пин код '.$row["status"].'</td>';`. И никаких проверок не надо... ну кроме как на ошибку при обращении к серверу / выполнении запроса.

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестировать.

Comment: Как вы рекомендовали бы исправить мою базу данных, что использовать вместо int и в каком формате хранить дату?

Comment: @Иван *что использовать вместо int и в каком формате хранить дату?* Если Вам необходимо учитывать зоны времени, то TIMESTAMP. Если нет, или если Вы хотите полностью контролировать зону времени клиентским кодом - то DATETIME.